# Customizing SP Attach File Modal

Tags: 2013, custom-form, modal-dialog, dialog-framework

I was wondering if it is possible to have BOTH an html and url included in the options you pass to `SP.UI.Dialog` for the Attach File dialog.  I can embed the link into a div but it shows the entire page unlike in the modal where it only shows the pertinent info...

I was hoping I could open up the SP version of the Attach File modal and then add in custom HTML to it versus creating my own modal and trying to embed the attach file page.  Is this possible?  If not, could I add it via jQuery possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the Dialog without the entire page using below URL

```
https://siteurl/_layouts/15/AttachFile.aspx?IsDlg=1
```

Comment: thank you!!! It works...now I feel stupid...all I had to do is add the $IsDlg=1 to then end of the url query with the list ID and item #

Comment: It shows properly but it doesn't work right...when I add a file and hit OK I get the following error: "Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference when it attempts to set the ScrollPosition values